# Google Mirror API throwing BadStatusLine exception (Python)

Tags: python, google-mirror-api, google-glass

When using the Mirror API, I randomly get a "BadStatusLine" exception from several API calls, including `timeline().insert` and `timeline.list`. From trolling around SO for simliar problems in python, I suspect this is some kind of malformed response from the server.

It seems to happen randomly and possibly after a period of not using the API. Here's a sample stack trace:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "service.py", line 61, in receive_message
     self.process_user_chat(msg)
   File "service.py", line 304, in process_user_chat
     self.upsert_timeline_item(sourceItemId, body)
   File "service.py", line 86, in upsert_timeline_item
     new_item = self.glass_service.timeline().insert(body=body).execute()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 676, in execute
     body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 494, in new_request
     self._refresh(request_orig)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 653, in _refresh
     self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 682, in _do_refresh_request
     self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
     response = conn.getresponse()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1034, in getresponse
    response.begin()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
     raise BadStatusLine(line)
 BadStatusLine: ''
```

This code works most of the time, but every once in a while I get a response like this.

---

**Update:** My code was creating the Google API classes and using them for the duration of the service. Once it got time to renew my `oauth2` token (1 hour) I'd get this error once or twice then it would start working again. I was able to refactor my code so it creates the API classes on each request and the problem has gone away. This appears to be a known bug in Google's API, see the selected answer from Anthony Tuininga for more information.

Comment: Is there a question, or is this simply an observation?

Comment: LOL well I guess the question would be how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem appears to be a known issue. I have experienced it myself consistently. If a single file takes more than 1 hour to upload, then this error occurs. If a *different* file is uploaded the API refreshes the token properly. See this bug for more information. It is apparently not fixed yet and there is no ETA on when it will be fixed. :-(

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=231

Comment: My theory has been that the Google Api's objects aren't designed to be long-lived. I was creating API instances and then using them for the lifetime of the service. Once they had been running for long enough to require a refresh I'd get this error once or twice then it would start working again. I've refactored my code so I create the API classes on each request and the problem has gone away. I wonder if you could use the same strategy? Once you get the error on a resumable upload, try recreating the API class and continuing?

Comment: My problem is that I am uploading a file of size 25 MB and on quite a few occasions it takes longer than an hour. I'm not sure how to resume the upload but starting a new upload works just fine. I have been searching for a solution to this problem for some time and it is apparently a common issue. The API does not apparently handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The status line is the first line returned by an HTTP response.  It contains the status code like 200, 404, 500, etc.  If the httplib can't read the status line, it can't read anything about it.

The problem is often caused by a bad HTTP request or a server problem.  Try making the request from your browser to see what it shows you.  Alternatively, you can use `curl` or `wget` to make the request.

Your stack trace shows `oauth2client` so you must be attempting the OAuth 2 protocol.  Maybe the previous request caused the error, and this one simply met a closed door at the server.  Logging all requests and responses may help you see what caused the failure.

Comment: This all makes sense to me. I'm using the Google API / Mirror API and this is all buried in it, so I'm hoping for an answer that doesn't require me hacking into Google's code to make it work.

Comment: It seems to happen after a period of inactivity from my service (well maybe, that's just a theory.) It always seems to fail while trying to refresh the oauth2 token, but then future requests will in fact work. I was wondering if perhaps a connection pool has been closed by httplib2 but somehow the system isn't fully aware of it and thus causing the error, then later requests create a new connection to the server. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It may be as simple as their server was too busy to respond, and you need to retry the request.  Examining the response headers should help you.