# Upload file larger than 70 MB to google drive using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Hi I tried to upload files to Google drive using  following code

```
def upload_file(self,file_name,path):

    parents = None
    if not path == None:
        parents = self.create_path(path)
    mime_type = self.get_mime_type_for(file_name)
    file_id = self.check_file_exist(file_name,parents,mime_type)
    if file_id == None:

        print "creating file...........",file_name                      
        print "mime_type",mime_type
        media = MediaFileUpload(file_name, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
        body = {
            'title': file_name,
            'description': 'A test document',
            'mimeType': mime_type
        }
        if not parents == None:
            body['parents'] = [{'id': parents}]
        f = self.drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media).execute()
    else:
        print "file exists........... updating"
        self.update_file(file_id, file_name)
```

this code works for smaller files (tested up to 25MB). But if i tried to upload large files(70MB) the system gives the error message

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "googledrive.py", line 176, in
>
> gd.upload_file("test.mp4","/media/media")
>
> File "googledrive.py", line 122, in upload_file
>
> f = self.drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media).execute()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
>
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 688, in execute
>
> _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http, num_retries=num_retries)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
>
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 867, in next_chunk
>
> headers=headers)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
>
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 490, in new_request
>
> redirections, connection_type)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1570, in request
>
> (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1317, in _request
>
> (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
>
> response = conn.getresponse()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
>
> response.begin()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
>
> version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
>
> raise BadStatusLine(line)
>
> ```
> httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
> ```

Comment: How long until it fails? might be relevant: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=231 According to the docs, it should have a max of 10 gigs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your upload is taking longer than about an hour, your token might expire and your download will fail. This is a known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=231).

Also, see [Google Mirror API throwing BadStatusLine exception (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180433/google-mirror-api-throwing-badstatusline-exception-python)